# Vimeo API issues on MAC

Tags: javascript, vimeo

Running the following code for the Vimeo JS API works as expected on Windows i.e. console logs and runs the 2 functions. (https://player.vimeo.com/api/player.js)

```
const player = new Vimeo.Player(document.getElementById('secondaryCameraSetUpIframe'));
player.on('ended', function () {
  console.log('video has ended');
  setCookieToExpireInOneDay();
  disableLaunchExamButton(false);
});
```

However, on MAC through Chrome Browser it's failing to do any of this and returning net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT for these two endpoints

1. POST [https://fresnel.vimeocdn.com/add/player-stats?beacon=1&session-id={id}](https://fresnel.vimeocdn.com/add/player-stats?beacon=1&session-id=%7Bid%7D)
2. POST https://player-telemetry.vimeo.com/player-events/log/partial

Comment: `net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT` can mean that the script is blocked by an adblocker